# DLL VCTRS not found when loading ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, vctrs

I use R 4.1.3. My problem is that after I installed ggplot2, I try to load the package by typing `library(ggplot2)`, however the following message comes up:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in
> library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib): DLL not found: maybe not
> installed for this architecture?

When I look in my R/win-library/4.1 folder (which oddly is placed in my onedrive, don't know how to change that), I can see that a folder called VCTRS already is installed, but not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

I tried reinstalling everything, installing r tools and installing the package and restarting my pc but nothing seems to be working.